# Do I need to call the batch file everytime i execute a ROS2 command in a new terminal

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am pretty new to ROS2. I have already installed ROS2 on Windows 10 as given in the installation guide. I get an error everytime i try to run a ROS2 command saying "ROS 2 is not recognised as an internal command". I know calling the batch file first resolves this error. But my question is do i need to call it everytime i write a command in the new terminal or have i done something wrong in the installation process ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285886/do-i-need-to-call-the-batch-file-everytime-i-execute-a-ros2-command-in-a-new-terminal/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No you haven't missed anything in the setup instructions. You need to call the `setup.bat` file in each terminal before running ROS 2. This is just like how you need to call the `vcvarsall.bat` file to get access to the visual studio command line tools in a command prompt.

On Linux and macOS you could automate this step by putting this "setup sourcing" command in your `~/.bashrc` or similar. I'm not aware of something like this for cmd.exe which is global, though there might be.

Instead you could setup a shortcut which executed cmd.exe and the setup file as it opened the new command prompt. I don't have a link to a tutorial or anything like that, but you could look at the visual studio "developer command prompt" shortcuts, which do something similar, to see how they are setup.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1